# Views pager when view is running on Node Id

Tags: views, nodes, paging

I have a view with a contextual filter of Nid running to display the current node.
Does anyone know of a way to set up pagers within a view that can handle paging to  next/prev nodes? So a 'next' link for the subsequent node and a 'prev' link to show previous node.

I would normally use [custom pagers](http://drupal.org/project/custom_pagers) for this but this module does not work properly with views 3 that I have installed.

Any help or an alternative to custom pagers would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used [Previous/Next API](http://drupal.org/project/prev_next) for this kind of situation (it's only dev, but it worked for me, YMMV).

Comment: Thanks a lot. The module is not as easy to implement as custom pages for different content types but still a great solution.